.NET 8.0 - InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'bookingData' on type 'BerHUB_reverse.Components.Pages.CreateBookingPage'
today I've got the following error code:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'bookingData' on type 'BerHUB_reverse.Components.Pages.CreateBookingPage'. There is no registered service of type 'BerHUB_reverse.DataAccessLayer.Repositories.IBookingData`1[BerHUB_reverse.Components.Pages.Booking]'. 
In the CreateBookingPage.razor file is a DI for the Interface, but it wont recognize it.
In line 16 of the CreateBookingPage.razor:
@inject IBookingData<Booking> bookingData
I also write a using statement for the model, data class and interface:
@using BerHUB_reverse.DataAccessLayer.Repositories
@using BerHUB_reverse.DataAccessLayer.Data
@using BerHUB_reverse.Models 

IBookingData.cs:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BerHUB_reverse.DataAccessLayer.Repositories
{
    public interface IBookingData<T> where T : class
    {
        Task<int> InsertBooking(T model);
    }
}

BookingData.cs:
using BerHUB_reverse.DataAccessLayer.Repositories;
using BerHUB_reverse.DataAccessLayer.SqlDataAccess;
using BerHUB_reverse.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BerHUB_reverse.DataAccessLayer.Data
{
    public class BookingData : IBookingData<Booking>
    {
        private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

        public BookingData(ISqlDataAccess db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public async Task<int> InsertBooking(Booking model)
        {
            var parameters = new {model.Hostname, model.TimeslotID};
            int insertedId = await _db.SaveDataReturnId("sp_InsertBooking", parameters);
            return insertedId;
        }
    }    
}

I also added it to the Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBookingData<Booking>, BookingData>();
I dont know where the error comes from, maybe you could help me.

After long searching the problem must be with the Dependency Injection. Blazor could not found the IBookingData interface.

The answer to this question is you are not allowed to use the name "Booking" as a name for a model, a class or something like this in Blazor. I changed the "Booking" class to BookingModel and now it working perfectly fine for me.
